# I think i have been locked out of Autodesk, what can i do?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I have integrated viewer into a webapp, and everythign was going fine, but i think i hit the data management api too many times trying to figure it out, and now i get these errors when trying to use the viewer:

[image: console.log errors using the viewer]

I also get rejected when trying to view which hubs I have access to using the data management api. Other folks on my team can still use the exact same viewer, so it is just me. Any ideas?